# Transparent menu with sections 'cut-out'

Tags: html, css

I'm asked to create a html/css menu such as the following picture:

[image]

This looks a simple menu to me, wasn't it by the fact that it has 'cut-out' sections between the menu items. I don't think it's clear from the image but the upper and lower part of the menu are connected with one another. Let me explain that with the use of a picture created in paint:

[image]

The grey area's are the 'cut-out' parts I was talking about. The upper and lower part are connected with each other.

I hope this is clear and I'm hoping for someone to help. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Herewith some code sample and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7d9v/), this is how far I got.

```
<div class="behandelingen-en-prijzen">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.behandelingen-en-prijzen
{

}

.behandelingen-en-prijzen ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.behandelingen-en-prijzen ul li a
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: have to tried anything? (sorry if sounded rude :) )

Comment: You don't sound rude at all - but no, I couldn't come up with anything sadly enough :-(

Comment: It's very difficult to help without at least seeing the markup for your menu. You must have tried something surely?

Comment: I see the issue you are trying to solve. I would just ask the designer to remove the cut-out section and make the entire vertical transparent instead of the cut-out.

Comment: @Huangism it needs to be responsive, so i'd like to scale it eventually, which isn't really possible with a full picture

Comment: @MarkvanVelthoven sure it is, you can scale a picture. You can always use an actual image for the background and give it 100% width so it scales to the container. Unless you are only targeting modern browsers, css3 background props will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it without using images

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="cutout">
     <li>
        <a href="#">home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">about</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body{ background: url(https://i.imgur.com/lsoomRq.jpg); }
.cutout{ list-style: none; padding: 0; border: 3px solid rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.8);  }
.cutout, .cutout li{ height: 40px; line-height: 40px; overflow: hidden;  }
.cutout li{ float: left; width: 33.33%; text-align: center; }
.cutout a{ display: block; margin-right: 3px; background: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.8); color: #555; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: sans-serif; text-decoration: none;}
.cutout a:hover{background: #fff}
.cutout li:last-child{ float: right; }
.cutout li:last-child a{margin-right: 0; }
```

Comment: You just beat me to it! Great answer!

Comment: Great, works perfectly, didn't know you could solve it like this!

Answer (score 1):

Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a7d9v/3/

Removed padding from li and left 1px, added padding to a and floated the li - left.

```
<div class="behandelingen-en-prijzen">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="no-border" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.behandelingen-en-prijzen ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.behandelingen-en-prijzen ul li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.behandelingen-en-prijzen ul li a
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.behandelingen-en-prijzen ul li a.no-border {
   border: none;
}
```

Comment: Also a neat solution! Although you can use :last-child on the last li element, so the no-border class becomes obsolete. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a7d9v/6/